# Dart: can i make a recursion end after meeting a condition

Tags: function, dart, recursion, user-input

I wrote a function for name collection, if the user omits the input, the function returns "you skipped .." and asks for it again, but the function keeps recursing even after i enter an input, it still keeps asking over and over like i left it blank

```
void main() {
  print('what is your name bro:');
  String? name = stdin.readLineSync();
  void ncon() {
    if (name == '') {
      print('Name can\'t be empty \n\nWhat is your name bro:');
      String? name = stdin.readLineSync();
      ncon();

    }
  }

  ncon();
  print('How are you $name');
}
```

I want the recursion to end if user finally inputs a name and just skip to `print('How are you $name');`

Comment: You'd end a recursive function the same way you'd end from any other function: a `return` statement, throwing an exception, or not having any more statements to execute.  You should use a `while` loop here though.

Comment: i see, thanks, i'll not that for next time, I'm trying while loop rn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make this recursive. Use a `while` loop!

```dart
void main() {
  print('what is your name bro:');
  var name = stdin.readLineSync()!;

  while (name.isEmpty) {
    print('Name can\'t be empty \n\nWhat is your name bro:');
    name = stdin.readLineSync()!;
  }
  print('How are you $name');
}
```

Comment: there is a null error
Error: Property 'isEmpty' cannot be accessed on 'String?' because it is potentially null.
Try accessing using ?.

Comment: 'while (name!.isEmpty)' i added a null safe after the value, thanks a lotttttttttt